# mini displayport not detected - hd4400, thinkpad x240

Tags: display, intel-graphics, thinkpad, displayport

I have a thinkpad x240 with a hd4400 graphics card running on ubuntu 14.04. I've been trying to get the mini displayport working with no success.

I have an apple mini-dp to vga adapater. I know the physical port / adapter combination is working: if I select the mini displayport in the bios as the default display, it's going to show grub / loading information on the screen attached to it, but switches back to the main laptop screen as soon as I get to the login.

If I attach a screen to the adapter, it is not detected (neither in Displays, nor in xrandr, and no line shows in dmesg / Xorg.0.log).

Here is some information regarding the system I'm running and the things I tried:

- kernel: tried with both the default kernel and am now running the 3.16.3 kernel.
- installed the intel drivers from the intel linux graphics installer (after seeing that the mini dp doesn't work with stock intel drivers).
- Xorg.0.log available [from here](https://gist.github.com/ugocupcic/ab84b652120595764a9b)
- tried to force the display using a combination of `xrandr --newmode` /  `xrandr --addmode` with no success.

Feel free to ask me more data as I'm not sure what's relevant. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried using a display port screen instead of my old vga screen + minidp to vga adapter and this configuration is working.